# MySQL: How to optimize this simple GROUP BY+ORDER BY query?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have one mysql table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
`Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`SenderId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`ReceiverId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`DateSent` datetime NOT NULL,
`Notified` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
KEY `ReceiverId_SenderId` (`ReceiverId`,`SenderId`),
KEY `SenderId` (`SenderId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

The table is populated with 10.000 random rows for testing by using the following procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `FillTest`(IN `cnt` INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;

DECLARE intSenderId INT;
DECLARE intReceiverId INT;
DECLARE dtDateSent DATE;

DECLARE blnNotified INT;

WHILE (i<=cnt) DO
SET intSenderId = FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * 50));
SET intReceiverId = FLOOR(51 + (RAND() * 50));
SET dtDateSent = str_to_date(concat(floor(1 + rand() * (12-1)),'-',floor(1 + rand() * (28 -1)),'-','2008'),'%m-%d-%Y');

SET blnNotified = FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * 2))-1;

INSERT INTO test (SenderId, ReceiverId, DateSent, Notified)
VALUES(intSenderId,intReceiverId,dtDateSent, blnNotified);

SET i=i+1;
END WHILE;

END//
DELIMITER ;
CALL `FillTest`(10000);
```

**The problem:**

I need to write a query which will **group by ‘SenderId, ReceiverId’** and return the **first 100 highest Ids** of each group, **ordered by Id in ascending order**.

I played with GROUP BY, ORDER BY and MAX(Id), but the query was too slow, so I came up with this query:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE t1.*
FROM test t1
LEFT JOIN test t2 ON (t1.ReceiverId = t2.ReceiverId AND t1.SenderId = t2.SenderId AND     t1.Id < t2.Id)
WHERE t2.Id IS NULL
ORDER BY t1.Id ASC
LIMIT 100;
```

The above query returns the correct data, but it becomes too slow when the `test` table has more than 150.000 rows . On 150.000 rows the above query needs 7 seconds to complete. I expect the `test` table to have between 500.000 – 1M rows, and the query needs to return the correct data in less than 3 sec. If it’s not possible to fetch the correct data in less than 3 sec, than I need it to fetch the data using the fastest query possible.

So, how can the above query be optimized so that it runs faster?

Comment: your comment about grouping by max(id) too slow, but now ordering by ID limit 100... This will always return the same 100 first records (mostly... until a missing sender/receiver combinations are added to the set...  Do you always want the up-front instances, or most recent (highest 100) instances of missing sender/receiver pairs.

Comment: On the one hand, you say you want the 100 highest id numbers for each sender/receiver group. On the other hand, you say the query you came up with returns the right data. But it only returns 100 rows. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

Reasons why this query may be slow:

- It's a lot of data. Lots of it may be returned. It returns the last record for each SenderId/ReceiverId combination.
- The division of the data (many Sender/Receiver combinations, or relative few of them, but with multiple 'versions'.
- The whole result set must be sorted by MySQL, because you need the first 100 records, sorted by Id.

These make it hard to optimize this query **without restructuring the data**. A few suggestions to try:

- You could try using `NOT EXISTS`, although I doubt if it would help.

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE t1.*
FROM test t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 'x' 
    FROM test t2 
    WHERE t1.ReceiverId = t2.ReceiverId AND t1.SenderId = t2.SenderId AND t1.Id < t2.Id)
ORDER BY t1.Id ASC
LIMIT 100;
```

- You could try using proper indexes on ReceiverId, SenderId and Id. Experiment with creating a combined index on the three columns. Try two versions, one with Id being the first column, and one with Id being the last.

**With slight database modifications:**
- You could save a combination of SenderId/ReceiverId in a separate table with a LastId pointing to the record you want.
- You could save a 'PreviousId' with each record, keeping it NULL for the last record per Sender/Receiver. You only need to query the records where previousId is null.